# How to generate ethereum address derived from xpub in PHP?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, private-key

How to generate ethereum address derived from xpub in PHP?

I am trying to generate ethereum address similar like below link does for bitcoin.

https://github.com/blockchain/receive-payments-demos

I want to use one xpub and generate multiple ethereum addresses.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find complete tool for it here: https://github.com/dukei/hd-wallet-derive

`$ ./hd-wallet-derive.php -g --key=xpub6BfKpqjTwvH21wJGWEfxLppb8sU7C6FJge2kWb9315oP4ZVqCXG29cdUtkyu7YQhHyfA5nt63nzcNZHYmqXYHDxYo8mm1Xq1dAC7YtodwUR --numderive=3 --cols=path,eth_address`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather generate address client side using js. (have a look at https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet as an example and in particular the https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/blob/mercury/app/scripts/myetherwallet.js) The advantage is that, as the generation is fully done client side, the user can check (by looking at the network) that no copy of her/his private key ever reach the server.